# Resizing UiView Height With Dynamic Content in UIScrollView (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I have UIView inside of a UIScrollView and have connected them from Interface Builder:

```
@IBOutlet weak var articleScroll: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var articleSubview: UIView!
```

I have dynamic content going into the UIView and I want its height to be drawn as large as the content (so that it scrolls). I thought that using .last to find origin.y in combination with the height of the content would do it:

```
var scroll = self.articleSubview
var lastItem = scroll.subviews.last as! UIView
var lastOriginY = lastItem.frame.origin.y
var lastHeight = lastItem.frame.size.height
var finalHeight = lastOriginY+lastHeight

    scroll.frame = CGRectMake(0 , 0, lastItem.frame.size.width, finalHeight)
```

The build succeeded but nothing scrolled. I tried adding:

```
articleScroll.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

But it didn't make a difference. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

It has been solved. The actual scroll view has to be resized, not the child view. Do not use the scroll.frame, instead "contentSize" on the UIScrollView was the way to go.:

```
self.articleScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(lastItem.frame.size.width, finalHeight)
```

Comment: Do you understand about the scroll view's `contentSize`?

Comment: @matt, you tipped me off exactly where I made the mistake. I should have resized the scroll view and not the content. Duh... Please give an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, glad I was able to jog you in the right direction. Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scrollability (is that a word?) of a UIScrollView depends upon its `contentSize` in relation to its bounds size. The idea is to make the `contentSize` embrace the content; if it is bigger than the scroll view's bounds size, the user can scroll.

Your code doesn't set the `contentSize` anywhere. It needs to!

Answer (score 0):

Resizing your scroll, scroll view have a method called `scroll.scrollRectToVisible(<rect: CGRect>, animated: <Bool>)`
to scroll to the frame.